# add property to object

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript, basil.js

With Indesign scripting, why can't I add properties to an object?
I get an error

> Object does not support the property or method 'foo'

```
items = b.items(b.layer("s_labels"));

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].fit(FitOptions.frameToContent);

    items[i].foo = "bar";
    // other attempt
    items[i]["foo"] = "bar";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you simply are not allowed to add new fields or methods to javascript objects that are provided by InDesign.

Comment: I think more of it as a JS API to the InDesign DOM. What you could do is passing JSON to a label and evaluate it later. `item[i].label = JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"});var obj = JSON.parse(item[i].label);`

Comment: right, if you just want to attach information then fields like label could be a good starting point to hack something together!